# GREP and ssh command to output variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to collect 1 row from my ssh command to a remote host by using grep to get the row with the ip address that I want. However, my variable "TARGET_NODE_IP" seems to not be matching my grep cmd.. While if I put the IP address manually e.g "192..." in the grep command it will match the row I want, but if I get the hostname -i to the TARGET_NODE_IP variable by ssh the same ip address doesn't match.. anyone have any feedback? Thank You.

```
        if ( ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q  $SOURCE_NODE_FQDN '[ -e $NODETOOL]' ); then
            BASE_CMD="ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q  $SOURCE_NODE_FQDN"
            TARGET_NODE_IP=$(ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q $TARGET_NODE_FQDN hostname -i)
            TARGET_NODE_STATUS=`$BASE_CMD $NODETOOL status | awk '{print $1,$2}' | tail -n+6 | sed '/^\s*$/d' | grep "$TARGET_NODE_IP"`
            echo "$TARGET_NODE_STATUS"
        fi
```

... | grep "$TARGET_NODE_IP"`  does not work.. returns blank

... | grep "192.xxx.xxx"` works... returns row i want.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the value of TARGET_NODE_IP before passing it to grep? Maybe there is some issue in the command you're using to assign TARGET_NODE_IP.

Comment: Why the subshell `(...)` in the `if` condition? Or is that a typo?

Comment: Did you check that `TARGET_NODE_IP` gets a correct value?

Comment: Thanks all, indeed, TARGET_NODE_IP was set to the wrong value.